# Swift / UITableView insert random row into section to publish AdMob Ads

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I want to publish Ads. I want the Ads to be inside a `UITableView`. Randomly within the regular content. My `UITableView` is easily populated like that:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return example.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("newEventsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExampleCell
        return cell
}
```

How do I smuggle a `UITableViewCell as! AdCell` randomly into the UITableView? Help is very appreciated.

For example like that:

```
    [regular content]
-------------------------
    [    ad  cell   ]
-------------------------
    [regular content]
-------------------------
    [regular content]
-------------------------
    [regular content]
-------------------------
    [    ad  cell   ]
-------------------------
    [regular content]
-------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Can create a new prototype cell and make it with a new identifier like "Ads", then you just modify your array to add sometimes (Randomly) the add cell, For example, if you array is a model, you can make a variable isAnAds, and when evaluating what cell to return, you make an if condition that shows a normal cell if isAnAds is false or an "Ads" cell if isAnAds is true. I have use this method to have 2 different type of Cells on the same table view, hope it helps :D

Comment: Here is a picture of an example code that gives 2 different cell types to the same table view, Here my condition was just for testing, and then it was the indexPath.row == 1 I use the Ad Cell in your canse, and on the other case I just used the normal cell type. [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24078452/Screen%20Shot%202016-09-24%20at%203.06.31%20PM.png)

Comment: i'll try your solution today

Comment: so to get you straight... I'm using my current array "TestArray" (f.e.), filled with my desired content. and ADD an Ad element into this array? can you provide any kind of code to make you idea more understandable?

Comment: the code from your picture just decides what cell to take? but based on what condition

Comment: That was just an example, and it just decides based on if it is the number 1, that meaning being the second cell, But You can make it with a random range based on your needs.

Comment: BTW, your array is just a string, int bool or something like that array? or it is an array of a custom made class? The Ideal scenario is that it should be an array of a custom class.

Comment: array of custom class

Comment: Great, then you can append to that array, on random positions an object with the variable isAnAds to True, and then use that as a condition.